# How to implement Twitter+OAuth third party

Tags: objective-c, twitter, instantiation

I have been testing to implement Twitter Login using Twitter+OAuth third party download from: https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone/tree/master/Twitter%2BOAuth

This snippet is to instantiate SA_OAuthTwitterEngine.

```
SA_OAuthTwitterEngine *engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate: self];
```

However, if this instantiate is implemented in subclass of NSObject (not within UIViewController: because the demo in the Twitter+OAuth intend to instantiate within UIViewController "viewWillAppear"), you won't be able to instantiate at all.

*engine and self will be nil which is not right behaviour in this case. 
To sum up, what I want to do is to implement Twitter login using this third party within a subclass of NSObject.

Please help me overcome this issue as soon as possible.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using Twitter+OAuth for new projects; iOS has included built-in Twitter support since iOS 5; that's what should be used.

Comment: Thank you Ben. I have taken over a project from my college who has been using your third party. That's why I have tried to use it. OK, I will take a look!